# gnome shell choppy/flicking after --replace (nvidia gfx)

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, gnome, nouveau

after regular updates/upgrades my gnome-shell stopped working and got into *fallback mode*.
I have tested installing nvidia drivers (i have an nvidia gfx), removing them, blacklisting *nouveau* and other basic stuff i have found here on the question-board but none seem to work so far. With a `gnome shell --replace` i can get the shell running. But its always buggy/choppy and unusable. Even with the windowskey / superkey the dashboard just flickers on/off/on/off and parts of the ui just vanishes and reappers all the time. Like i said... unusable.

I'm using:

- GNOME Shell 3.4.1
- Ubuntu 12.04

Any ideas i can tryout? Thanks for the help in advance.

**Edit:** gnome-shell only works with nouveau. nvidia does give me an error when i try `--replace`

```
Errormessage: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

Seems like my nvidia drivers are not loading. In `jockey-gtk` its displaying: *activated but not in use*

**Solution:**
Restart & *press shift*. Start in *rescue mode*. Start *failsafeX* to unlock filesystem & cancel back to terminal. Open root terminal

```
cd /tmp/
wget download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/285.05.09/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-285.05.09.run
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86-285.05.09.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-285.05.09.run
```

- *You can also get the latest drivers as @dibs suggested. For me on my old system these drivers ran just fine. Make sure to blacklist nouveau, tho.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rolling your nvidia driver back to 295.40, this just fixed a few issues like this with my 12.04 x64.